# Can't read post data in php api with slim 3

Tags: php, angular, api, slim-3

I have a frontend in angular which consume API in php/slim3.

I call a php api with this post request :

```
return this.http.post<any>(API_URL + '/user', { data: userData });
```

With these form values  : {name: "john", age: "25"}

in the api I have this code :

```
$app->post('/user', function (\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response) {
    $input = $request->getParams();
    $name = $input['name'];
    $age = $input["age"];
    echo json_encode($name);
}
```

When i run my app it returns null instead of name, but when i use postman with the same values it returns the good value.

I have tried with :

```
$input = $request->getParsedBody();
```

it's the same result.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: hi, first - check what you have in the response in dev tools. `getParsedBody()` seems okay. Second - check if angular http response type can be set to json. Third - use slim withJson method for the response. Also your request/response objects seem to look different then in the docs https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#how-to-get-the-request-object

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have found the error : I have changed this :
return this.http.post<any>(API_URL + '/user', { data: userData });
to this :
return this.http.post<any>(API_URL + '/user', userData);

Comment: I think you need to stringify your user data: `{ data: JSON.stringify(userData) }`. I don't think Angular does it for you.